# FFMPEG : merge images and audio to create a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg. I have a requirement where I want to merge 500 images with one audio and generate an output video. Here it is required that each image is displayed for 5 seconds and then next image is displayed for 5 seconds and so on. The audio keeps on playing continuously in the background. For this I am using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=480:360 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

The above command generates the correct video but that video does not play on VLC player. Also if I play it at 2x or 3x speed (we have to give user this option), then it hangs on a single frame.

However, if I modify the command and use "-r 25" option then the video playes in VLC player and also works correctly at 2X and 3x speed.

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=480:360 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 out_25f.mp4
```

Using the above command is not desired as it generates a very large video(4x bigger) and takes up 5x more time to generate.

Please share help me in optimizing the command I am using to generate desired result.

Comment: Don't have to set `25`. `5` should do.

Comment: Setting output framerate is increasing the time taken to generate the video which is not desired. Is there any other way to achieve this without increasing the creation time?

Comment: Not for VLC playback. Add `-preset veryfast` for quicker gen